# XSL template match pattern applies to all child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a snippet of my stylesheet:

```html
 <xsl:template name="root" match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/office:document-content/office:body/office:text"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- -->
 <xsl:template name="text" match="office:text">
  <text>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </text>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text:h|text:p">
  <para>
   <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
  </para>
 </xsl:template>
```

And this is the input [xml file](https://github.com/RadoslavMarinov/stack-show/blob/7e7b62ad194e19b3139cd9f3e325d1f2ad562b7e/xml/content.xml). Snippet:

```
<office:body>
    <office:text text:use-soft-page-breaks="true">
        <text:h text:style-name="P1" text:outline-level="1"><text:bookmark-start text:name="_Toc433035627"/>Права за<text:s/>достъп<text:s/>до ARISTA MDM<text:bookmark-end text:name="_Toc433035627"/></text:h>
        <text:p text:style-name="Normal">Входът в системата се осъществява с потребителско име и парола, като проверката на потребителското име и паролата се извършва в управляващия център ARISTA<text:s/>MDM или чрез активна директория (MS AD). При създаване на нов потребител има възможност да се определи дали вписването да се извършва от активната директория (MS AD) или управляващия център ARISTA MDM.</text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Header">Правата<text:s/>на потребителя конфигурират неговия достъп до:</text:p>
        <text:list text:style-name="LFO4" text:continue-numbering="true">
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListBullet2">Менюта и полета;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListBullet2">Параметри на устройства;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListBullet2">Части на структурата (папки, подпапки).<text:s/></text:p>
            </text:list-item>
        </text:list>
        <text:list text:style-name="LFO9" text:continue-numbering="true">
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListNumber2">Потребителите наследяват правата на ролите, които притежават. Единственият начин потребителите да получават или да им се отнемат права е чрез добавяне или премахване на<text:s/>ролите;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListNumber2">Паролите на потребителите, които се валидират към центъра<text:s/>ARISTA<text:s/>MDM<text:s/>могат да имат период на валидност. Периода на валидност се задава при създаване на потребителя;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListNumber2">При изтичане на периода на валидност на паролата, от потребителя се изисква да промени паролата си;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListNumber2">Всички действия на потребителите ще бъдат записвани и показвани в табличен вид, като информацията включва: потребителско име, действие, дата и час, модул и допълнителна информация;</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
            <text:list-item>
                <text:p text:style-name="ListNumber2">Записването на потребителските действия се активира или деактивира при създаване на нов потребител или промяна на данните на съществуващ.</text:p>
            </text:list-item>
        </text:list>
        <text:h text:style-name="Heading1" text:outline-level="1"><text:bookmark-start text:name="_Toc414357454"/><text:bookmark-start text:name="_Toc433035628"/>Вписване в ARISTA MDM<text:bookmark-end text:name="_Toc414357454"/><text:bookmark-end text:name="_Toc433035628"/></text:h>
        <text:p text:style-name="Normal">
            <text:span text:style-name="Strong">След въвеждане на адреса на системата се появява прозореца за вписване на потребители.</text:span>
        </text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Quote">За вписване в системата, операторът трябва да въведе съответното<text:s/>потребителско име и парола и да натисне бутон.</text:p>
    </office:text>
</office:body>
```

And this is the output I get:

```html
<text>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
 <para>1</para>
</text>
```

Please tell me why `<xsl:template match="text:h|text:p">` is applied for the other siblings (`text:list`) elements too? I has been explicitly told to be applied to `text:h` and `text:p` only. Excuse my poor English. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you @ michael.hor257k. Now my code can be reproduced :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that together explain the behavior you're seeing.

- First, realize that `<xsl:apply-templates />` applies to all children of the current node whenever the `select` attribute is missing, so you're applying templates to all element children of matched `office:text` elements (which includes those `text:list` elements).
- Second, although you have no templates that match those `text:list` elements, XSLT includes built-in templates, which are designed to allow recursive processing to continue whenever there is no successful pattern match, and that *do match* those elements. The built-in template that does that looks like this:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="*|/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

So, what's happening is that the built-in template matches the `text:list` children (because it matches all elements), then applies templates to *its* children, which results in further matches by your explicit template.

Comment: No, the built-in templates would not produce the given result.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood OP. He doesn't literally think that his template is matching `text:list` elements; he's wondering why the *children* of `text:list` are matching that template, when he never wrote any template to match or process the parent `text:list` in the first place. (You often have to read between the lines, which I don't think you've done here. Computers are literal. OP's often aren't.)

Comment: I've edited to make the fact this *his* template is *not* matching more explicit

Comment: I understand my post is may be vague, but it is due to my lack of knowledge to express myself in English. Somehow @Wayne Burkett guessed the point of my original post. Anyway thank you all guys, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, It is exactly the built-in templates that cause templates to be applied to the children of `<text:list>` and then to the children of `<text:list-item>` and then to their children -- among these to their `<text:p>` children -- at which case the specific template rule matching `text:h|text:p"` is selected for execution and produces the result that is reported. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me why `<xsl:template match="text:h|text:p">` is applied for
>   the other siblings (text:list) elements too?

What makes you think that it is? If you change:

```
<xsl:template match="text:h|text:p">
    <para>
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="text:h|text:p">
    <para>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

you will get a result of:

```
<text>
   <para>text:h</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:h</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
   <para>text:p</para>
</text>
```

so clearly the `text:list` elements were **not** processed.

Comment: *Of course* they were processed. You couldn't have gotten to the children `text:h` or `text:p` otherwise, which, if you read between the lines, is exactly what OP was asking.

Comment: @WayneBurkett No, they were not processed *by the template in question* - which **is** "*exactly what OP was asking*". Perhaps OP meant to ask why they were processed at all - I am not willing to guess.